# Gamblers Ruin Problem

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains, markov-process, gambling

I'm faced with this problem which is a slight variation on the classic Gamblers Ruin problem:

> Adam always starts with £$2$ and Bella with £$14$. At each point of the game, Adam can bet any integer amount of money £k, up to the amount of money he currently has; he then wins £$k$ with probability $0.4$ or loses £$k$ with probability $0.6$. 
>   Adam takes on a strategy where he bets £$2$ at each round – so
>   each round he wins £$2$ with probability $0.4$ or loses £$2$ with probability $0.6$. What is Adam's probability of winning the entire game?

Anyone got any idea how one would answer something like this? I can understand how to find the probability of ruin in the classic problem through conditioning on the first step, but this added twist of being able to bet £k to double your money throws me off. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery I see... Maybe I have over analysed this. I suppose it doesn’t actually saying anything about him actually betting £k!

Answer (score 2):

That phenomenon can't happen. Adam always bets £2, which means this is the ordinary gambler's ruin question with jumps of size 2 instead of 1.

Comment: Thanks again. Now, when I apply this to change in step and condition on the first step I form the linear difference equation:

$0.4r_{i+2} - r_i + 0.6r_{i-2} = 0$ subject to the boundary conditions.

Does this then translate to a characteristic equation of $0.4\lambda^4 - \lambda^2 +0.6 = 0$ ?

Comment: Here's one way you can check your own answer: notice that in this problem, the bettor starts at 2 and moves (in increments of 2) until reaching either 0 or 16. This is the same problem after relabeling as the ordinary gambler's ruin where a bettor starts at 1 and moves in increments of 1 until reaching either 0 or 8. Based on your comments, I think you are already comfortable with the second one, right?

Comment: I get that concept of thinking, but for the purpose of coherent workings, I’m just intrigued to know whether I have formatted the working correctly? Thank you again.

Comment: Ah I see! Now I get you. That’s a much easier way to approach it!

Comment: How could you go about figuring out the probability of winning if, when Adam gets to £8, he bets all of his money to double it or lose it?

Comment: Treat that case like an ordinary gambler's ruin problem on the boundaries 0 to 8. Then, break the "gets to 8" case into two sub-cases.